# Setup for Testing Custom Ethernet Cabling with Network Switch

Tags: electrical-engineering, networking

I am building a setup for performing a bandwidth test on custom cabling that carries two gigabit Ethernet channels. I have a working setup that includes two computers and two network switches to which the custom Ethernet cabling connects (see wiring diagram).

While not apparent in the wiring diagram, the network switches are included in the setup so that the fixture can accommodate several cabling configurations.  Each cabling configuration includes two Ethernet channels (ETH0 and ETH1) and both channels are tested simultaneously. Only one cabling configuration is tested at a time - therefore four ETH0 and four ETH1 ports are used during a test.
[image]

Is there any way to make this setup work with one network switch?  The aim is to configure the switch so that traffic between Computers 1 and 2 travels on the custom cabling under test.  I must prevent traffic from simply travelling between the switch ports to which the Computer Ethernet interfaces connect (as this would bypass the custom cabling under test).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the setup working with one network switch by creating four VLANs - two VLANs per subnet. All ports are set as "Untagged."  I also disabled STP.

I can force ETH0 traffic to traverses the custom cable by connecting one end of the cable to a port that is a member of VLAN1 and the other end of the cable to a port that is a member of VLAN2.

Likewise, ETH1 traffic traverses the custom cable when it is connected between one port that is a member of VLAN3 and another port that is a member of VLAN4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that the purpose you use a switch for is to connect multiple computers to an internet source. You can actually connect 4 or even 6 of these computers. Connecting individuals' switches to each computer does nothing really anything, it could make the computer run a little faster, but its main functionality is connecting multiple computers to an internet connection.